# Como ocultar un elemento con el id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buen día,

Estoy recibiendo por ajax los identificadores de los ids que quiero ocultar, ya intente hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

el cual no me ha funcionado.. y me gustaria que el elemento con el id que viene almacenado se oculte.

```js
        $.ajax(
        {
          url: "oculta_elementos_sin_permisos.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: {id_user:id_user},
          success:function(data)
          {
              let arreglo = data.split(',');
              
              for(var i=0; i<arreglo.length; i++)
              {
                $('#'+arreglo[i]).css("display", "none");
        
              }
          }
        });
```

yo recibo de mi archivo php la siguiente cadena "agregaruser,botoneliminar" que son mi ids, la cual la convierto en arreglo para poder usarlos individualmente y tratar de ocultarlos.

esto es lo que recibo: agregaruser,botoneliminar   <---- que son mis los nombre de los ids que debo ocultar

Comment: me parece ver que eso es una respuesta de una peticion ajax (por el `success:` lo deduzco), y no sabemos el formato del dato de vuelta.  ¿Puedes agregar a la pregunta la parte del servidor que devuelve ese valor y que dataType tienes puesto en la petición ajax?  Sino vamos a tener que ir adivinando que es eso y es probable que no acertemos.  Con un console.log(data) seria suficiente tambien supongo, porque dices que pueden ser varios y quizas el retorno es un array de objectos que tendrias que recorrer.

Comment: Segun me parece ahora, estas recibiendo datos separados por coma, pero no vemos como son o que son... dices que son id, pero los recibes entrecomillados?  haz un `console.log(data)` dentro de la function para ver exactamente que recibes y nos lo agregas a la pregunta, por favor

Comment: Algo mal debes tener en el `data` de vuelta, quizas viene encerrado en llaves o algo, pero tal como dices que lo recibes deberia funcionar:  Fijate en esto que si funciona: https://jsfiddle.net/qd1cey90/

Comment: es verdad en tu codigo si funciona, deja reviso bien la salida de la variable

Comment: ya me fusionó, uno de mis respuestas de ajax tenia un espacio. :D   muchas gracias @masterguru

Comment: No es mi código, es el tuyo :-)   Tan solo he plasmado en ese fiddle lo que tu dices que no te funciona

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro pues :-)  saludos!  Por cierto, ya que el problema era tipográfico mejor borra la pregunta para que nadie venga a perder el tiempo con ella, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tu respuesta data es un objeto y en las propiedades trae el id seria

```
$('#'+data.id).hide();
```

Te recomiendo agregarle algo de texto en tu html al id y no solo pongas el id, concatenale un texto por ejemplo

```
<div id="{{$objeto->id}}midiv"></div>
```

un ejemplo basado en php

```
$('#'+data.id+'midiv').hide();
```

Comment: ya lo intente asi.. pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: asgurate que al hacer el hide el elemento si exista en el dom